# How can I make a function enforce a specific string format for its argument?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm building a CLI where users can run some commands with additional arguments passed in a Linux-ish fashion.

To validate these options I've defined a dedicated decorator that performs some `str` processing to check wether this arguments are stated in the expected format.

As an example, there's a command `sell` that accepts as its first argument a string with the following syntax:

```
sell x:y=price
```

which would extract items from user's list ranging from `x` to `y` and list them on a virtual market for `price`. Here's a sample of how I'm doing this:

```
def validator(fun):
    def predicate(*args):
        if fun == sell:
            try:
                _range, price = args[0].split("=")
                _range = (int(i) for i in _range.split(":"))
                if len(_range) != 2 or _range[0] > _range[1]:
                    raise ValueError
                _range = range(*_range)
                
                fun(_range, price)

            except IndexError:
                print("Missing required argument: items")
                return
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Invalid argument items: {args[0]}")
                return

   return predicate

@validator()
def sell(*args):
    ...
```

So my question is: is there a less painful way to validate the string so that it complies with a specific format without all that processing?

Since I have implemented a lot of commands with a plethora of different arguments and options, if there's a way to, say, specify a generic model to which arguments must conform, I'd get rid of my decorator and solving the problem would be as easy as mapping functions to argument formats.

Comment: This seems like a perfect job for regex. Are you familiar with it? You can use https://regex101.com/ to craft and test out an expression.

Comment: You seem to have defined a Domain Specific Language. So your best choice could be write an EBNF grammar, and parse it with one of the many libraries available (check Lark, PLY, TatSu just to mention a few).

Comment: @RandomDavis Just checked out regex right know and it's perfect! Incredibly I knew nothing about it although it seems like a widely used lib. So, thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: @gimix This is an interesting approach too. Isn't EBNF the same used in python.gram to generate CPython parser itself? Still I think I'm going for regex just for the sake of simplicity. Thanks so much for the suggestion though!

Comment: @MaxShouman the grammar for CPython is quite complex, but you can have simpler grammars - you may want to have a look at the turtle graphics example for Lark, simple but far from trivial